# I need help to split parquet file up to a maximum of 1000 lines with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a function to upload a parquet file in s3 using boto3. I need to split the files with a maximum of 1000 lines and upload them.

```
for i, file_data in enumerate(data):
    file_path = f'{path}{i:06}.{file_format.name}'
    save_to_s3(bucket, file_path, file_data, content_type=file_format.value, **kwargs)


def save_to_s3(bucket: str | Bucket,
           path: str,
           data: (bytes | str),
           tags: dict[str, str] = None,
           content_type: str = "",
           metadata: dict[str, str] = None) -> None:

    bucket = Session(region_name=config.aws_region).resource('s3').Bucket(bucket)

    metadata = {**(metadata or {}), **{'created_by': config.spark_job_name}}
    data_hash = _get_content_hash(data)
    tags = _encode_object_tags(tags or {})

    bucket.put_object(
        Key=path,
        Body=data,
        ContentMD5=data_hash,
        Metadata=metadata,
        Tagging=tags,
        ContentType=content_type,
    )
```

Comment: Is your code returning an error? It is unclear what you need assistance with.

Comment: It is not returning an error, I would like some help to divide the parquet file into up to 1000 lines

Answer (score 1):

You can read the parquet file into a dataframe, get the size of the dataframe using `df.shape` and then divide the number of rows in the parquet by 1,000. Then loop from 0 to 1,000 and write a new Parquet file for each increment.

The starting Parquet file size may not divide evenly by 1k, so keep that in mind.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

num_to_divide = 1000

df = pd.read_parquet('your_file.parquet')

num_rows = df.shape[0]
split_size = math.ceil(num_rows / num_to_divide)

for i in range(0, num_rows, split_size):
    df_subset = df.iloc[i:i+split_size]
    df_subset.to_parquet(f'split_{i//split_size}.parquet')
```